# How to create "<filename>.view" extension file in j2ee

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, model-view-controller

I am new in j2ee. I have gone through a j2ee book. There is a web application named "Soccer" in which a file name "list_league.view" exists at "/" directory. This application using MVC and one Servlet file, So my question is how can i create these extension type file.

Content of Web.xml file:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>ListLeague</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>s1314.view.ListLeagueServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>ListLeague</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>list_league.view</servlet-class>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The /index.html page contain a anchor tag which refer to "list_leauge.view" file, below:

```
<h3>Player</h3>
<ul><li><a href="list_league.view">List all league</a></li>
<li>Register for a league(TBA)</li>
</ul>
```

ListLeaugeServlet.java

```
import s1314.model.League;

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
processRequest(request, response);
//Creats the set of league
leagueList=new LinkedList();
leagueList.add(new League("2003","Spring","Soccer League(Spring`03)"));
leagueList.add(new League("2003","Summer","Summer Soccer Fest"));
leagueList.add(new League("2003","Fall","Fall Soccer League"));
leagueList.add(new League("2004","Spring","Summer Soccer Fest"));
leagueList.add(new League("2004","Summer","Soccer League(Spring`03)"));
leagueList.add(new League("2004","Fall","Fall Soccer League"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand that `.view` is not the file type or extension. it is just the `url` pattern to intercept the requests to `spring container`.

You could the `.view` patterns to intercept the dispatcher servlet for your application. Check your 
`dispatcher-servlet.xml` to know the view folders under your view resolver

**Update** :

`ListLeague` servlet will be intercepted by the url `/list_league.view`.

Comment: Thanks...but i am not using spring framework.. and file name  "list_league.view" is present in project directory and what about the href="list_league.view"..How can in use it..please help

Comment: Can you post your web.xml completely or atleast the parts where you have the `url-pattern` tag

Comment: For your reference:      <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ListLeague</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>s1314.view.ListLeagueServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet><servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ListLeague</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/list_league.view</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

Comment: i could understand that . what is your doubt in that ?

Answer (score 0):

In servlet mapping you should specify a pattern for URLs handled by the servlet.

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>ListLeague</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.view</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The url pattern should be either the path or extension (other not considering here). Once the servlet is invoked it should return a view, i.e. some JSP page or another servlet. Suppose you have `list_league.jsp`:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html>
<head>
  <title>List League</title>
</head>
<body>
  <c:forEach var="row" items="${leagueList}">
    Year: <c:out value="${row.year}"/><br>
    Season: <c:out value="${row.season}"/><br>
    League: <c:out value="${row.league}"/><br>
  </c:forEach>
</body>
</html>
```

The servlet is a controller that forwards to JSP to return a view

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
processRequest(request, response);
  //Creats the set of league
  List<League> leagueList = new LinkedList<>();
  leagueList.add(new League("2003","Spring","Soccer League(Spring`03)"));
  leagueList.add(new League("2003","Summer","Summer Soccer Fest"));
  leagueList.add(new League("2003","Fall","Fall Soccer League"));
  leagueList.add(new League("2004","Spring","Summer Soccer Fest"));
  leagueList.add(new League("2004","Summer","Soccer League(Spring`03)"));
  leagueList.add(new League("2004","Fall","Fall Soccer League"));

  // forward a view with model
  request.setAttribute("leagueList", leagueList );
  request.getRequestDispatcher("list_league.jsp").forward(request, response); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I just replace <servlet-class>list_league.view</servlet-class> with <url-pattern>/list_league.view</url-pattern> in web.xml.